# SQL gives int values if schedule columns do not match

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables Schedules, and LoginTime. Schedules have colStart and colStop. LoginTime has colLogin, and colLogout. I have a SQL command that states that if the colLogin does not = colStart, then it will put a '1' value in a new column on a 3rd table. However I need to add a couple minute cushion so if the colLogin says 6:04AM and the colStart is 6:00AM then it'll report a 0 in the third column and table. Is there a way to have it determine this cushion?

Here is the code I've also used giving different variations:

```
SELECT loginlogout.[Name], loginlogout.[Login Time]
,      case 
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] = Schedules$.StartTime then 0 
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '5:56AM' AND '6:05AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '6:06AM' and '6:29AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '6:30AM' and '6:34AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '6:35AM' and '6:55AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '6:56AM' AND '7:05AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '7:06AM' AND '7:29AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '7:30AM' and '7:34AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '7:35AM' and '7:55AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '7:56AM' AND '8:05AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '8:06AM' AND '8:29AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '8:30AM' and '8:34AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '8:35AM' and '8:55AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '8:56AM' and '9:05AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '9:06AM' and '9:29AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '9:30AM' and '9:34AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '9:35AM' and '9:55AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '9:56AM' and '10:05AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '10:06AM' and '10:29AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '10:30AM' and '10:34AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '10:35AM' and '10:55AM' then 1
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '10:56AM' and '11:05AM' then 0
          when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '11:06AM' and '11:29AM' then 1
          else 1
       end as LoginInc 
into LoginIncidents 
FROM loginlogout 
JOIN Schedules$ 
  on loginlogout.[Name] = Schedules$.Name
```

however I learned if someone that is scheduled to start at 6:00AM and logs in at 6:32AM, there will be no incident since I have the `when loginlogout.[Login Time] BETWEEN '6:30AM' and '6:34AM' then 0`. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datediff` and check for minutes.

```
select
  case 
    when abs(datediff(minute, login, start)) between 0 and 5 then 1 
    else 0 
  end
```

If you want to have the negative difference not be the same as the positive, remove the `abs()` call above.

```
select
  case 
    when datediff(minute, login, start) between -4 and 5 then 1 
    else 0 
  end
```

Comment: brilliant, this did the trick and holy cow it made the rest of the command obsolete will mark as answered when avail.

Comment: if I changed 0 to -4 would that mean 4 minutes prior to login time also? cause that would be beneficial also

Comment: Not unless you remove the `abs()` function. If you do, then yes, you'd need to change it to `-4 and 5`. Or whatever combination you want.